# Simulate Network Tutorial

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, tutorials

So from the new tutorial website: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/#generate-local-keys-using-the-node-template

Few scrolls down there is a line: `./target/release/node-template \ --base-path /tmp/node01 \ --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \ --port 30333 \ --ws-port 9945 \ --rpc-port 9933 \ --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \ --validator \ --rpc-methods Unsafe \ --name MyNode01`

That is throwing the error? `./target/release/node-template \ --base-path /tmp/node01 \ --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \ --port 30333 \ --ws-port 9945 \ --rpc-port 9933 \ --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \ --validator \ --rpc-methods Unsafe \ --name MyNode01
error: Found argument ' --base-path' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
node-template [OPTIONS]
node-template `
What could be solution for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's now fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered what the problem was, problem was that the `\` backslashes where included in the block of code on website, so the new code without the backslashes would look like this:`./target/release/node-template --base-path /tmp/node01 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9933 --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode01`